# Access fragment view in parent activity

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view

I have an activity which displays multiple fragments depending on which one is selected.

I also have a button in this activity and I want to obtain a value from a specific fragment when this button is clicked.

How can I obtain this value?

I tried to get the view I wanted from the fragment from the activity as the code shows below but I can understand that it doesn't work since the fragment is still to be created.

```
onOffButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (onOffButton.text.contains("ON")) {
                onOffButton.text = "TURN OFF"

                var hoursPicker = findViewById<NumberPicker>(R.id.hoursPicker)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short version is you shouldn't do this, there are all kinds of complications (especially when you're trying to access the Fragment's Views).

It's even more complicated if the Fragment might not even be added to the UI at all! If it's not there, what value are you supposed to use? If you want to somehow create the Fragment just so it exists, and so you can read the value from its text box, then that's a sign the value really needs to be stored somewhere else, so you don't *need* the Fragment if you want to access it.

The easiest, recommended, and modern way to share data like this is with a `ViewModel`:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // setting a default value here!
    var currentHour: Int = 0
}
```

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    fun onCreate(...) {
        ...
        onOffButton.setOnClickListener {
            // access the data in the ViewModel
            val currentHour = model.currentHour
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    // using activityViewModels so we get the parent Activity's copy of the VM,
    // so we're all sharing the same object and seeing the same data
    val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    fun onViewCreated(...) {
        ...
        hoursPicker.setOnValueChangeListener { _, _, newValue ->
            // update the VM
            model.currentHour = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, you have this `ViewModel` object owned by the `Activity` and visible to its `Fragment`s. The VM outlives all of those components, so you don't lose data while an `Activity` is being destroyed on rotation, or when a `Fragment` isn't added to the UI, etc.

The VM is *the source of data*, everything else just reads from it, or updates it when something changes (like when the `Fragment` updates the variable when its number picker's value changes). This way, the Activity doesn't need to go "ask" the Fragment for info - it's stored in a central location, in the VM

This is the most basic way to use a `ViewModel` - you can start using `LiveData` and `Flow` objects to make different UI components observe data and react to changes too. For example, your button in your `Activity` could change some `enabled` state in the VM, and the `Fragment` (if it's added) will see that change and can do things like make the number picker visible or invisible.

It's way easier to coordinate this stuff with a `ViewModel`, so if you don't already know how to use them, I'd recommend learning it!